# I need to toggle display settings for a FAQ page. I made a working js script but it's super repetitive, how could I simplify this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm building a FAQ page that I want a clickable div with the question to display the answer. I wrote the following and it works, but it is not optimal in anyway because I have a function for each div. How can I simplify and optimize this code? I was thinking of using a for loop but got lost in the way.

Here's html:

**NOTE 1**: please don't mind the inline styles, I'm planning on moving those to the stylesheet but I was testing independently.

**NOTE 2:** the `{% include tags %}` are from liquid variables, the backend will render those properly so please ignore those.

```html
<div id="question-container1" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0;" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq1()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939; padding-top: 60px;">1. ¿Cuándo recibiré mi terrario?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq1" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Estaremos enviando los terrarios en la primera semana de diciembre.</p>
    
</div>

<div id="question-container2" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq2()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">2. ¿Cómo funciona el envío con plantas?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq2" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Utilizamos envío de UPS para el día siguiente, esto para que las plantas no pasen tanto tiempo en el traslado. Todos pedidos serán envíados de lunes a miércoles, esto para evitar ante cualquier percance, que las plantas pasen el fin de semana en las instalaciones de la mensajería. El envío no tiene costo.</p>
</div>

<div id="question-container3" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq3()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">3. ¿Cómo lo armo?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq3" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Te recomendamos armar tu terrario tan pronto lo recibas o colocar las plantas en una maceta para utilizarlas más adelante. Recuerda que puedes agregar más plantas ya estando armado el terrario. Sigue las instrucciones incluídas, o visita este <a href="">link.</a></p>
    
</div>

<div id="question-container4" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq4()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">4. ¿Qué tipos de pago aceptan?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq4" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Aceptamos pagos con tarjeta de crédito, débito, PayPal, pagos en efectivo en Oxxo o transferencia interbancaria SPEI.</p>
    
</div>
```

And here's javascript

```js
 const despliegueFaq1 = () => {        
        let x = document.getElementById ('esconder_faq1');
        if (x.style.display === "none"){
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    const despliegueFaq2 = () => {        
        let x = document.getElementById ('esconder_faq2');
        if (x.style.display === "none"){
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } 
    }
    const despliegueFaq3 = () => {        
        let x = document.getElementById ('esconder_faq3');
        if (x.style.display === "none"){
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    const despliegueFaq4 = () => {        
        let x = document.getElementById ('esconder_faq4');
        if (x.style.display === "none"){
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Give your div a class name. Then you can do the loop. Use ```getElementsByClassName("class_name")``` to get all div with same class name.

Answer (score 0):

On Javascript code, the content of each function is almost the same except the `id` like `esconder_faq1`, `esconder_faq2`...

So ids' are composed with `esconder_faq` prefix and number.

So you can make a new function that retrieves that index number as param and use that `number` to get the id like `"esconder_faq" + index` as follows.

On html, you can call the function with index number like `onclick=despliegueFaq(1)`.

```js
const despliegueFaq = (index) => {
  let x = document.getElementById('esconder_faq' + index);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="question-container1" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0;" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot"
  onclick="despliegueFaq(1)">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939; padding-top: 60px;">1. ¿Cuándo recibiré mi terrario?</h3>
  <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
  <p id="esconder_faq1" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Estaremos enviando los
    terrarios en la primera semana de diciembre.</p>

</div>

<div id="question-container2" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);"
  class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq(2)">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">2. ¿Cómo funciona el envío con plantas?</h3>
  <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
  <p id="esconder_faq2" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Utilizamos envío de
    UPS para el día siguiente, esto para que las plantas no pasen tanto tiempo en el traslado. Todos pedidos serán
    envíados de lunes a miércoles, esto para evitar ante cualquier percance, que las plantas pasen el fin de semana en
    las instalaciones de la mensajería. El envío no tiene costo.</p>
</div>

<div id="question-container3" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);"
  class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq(3)">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">3. ¿Cómo lo armo?</h3>
  <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
  <p id="esconder_faq3" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Te recomendamos armar
    tu terrario tan pronto lo recibas o colocar las plantas en una maceta para utilizarlas más adelante. Recuerda que
    puedes agregar más plantas ya estando armado el terrario. Sigue las instrucciones incluídas, o visita este <a
      href="">link.</a></p>

</div>

<div id="question-container4" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);"
  class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq(4)">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">4. ¿Qué tipos de pago aceptan?</h3>
  <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
  <p id="esconder_faq4" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Aceptamos pagos con
    tarjeta de crédito, débito, PayPal, pagos en efectivo en Oxxo o transferencia interbancaria SPEI.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution here is to use a `class` to identify all the `div`s you're interested in taking this action on. Let's say you give each of your `div`s the `class` name `question`:

```
<div class="question" id="question-container1" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0;" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq1()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939; padding-top: 60px;">1. ¿Cuándo recibiré mi terrario?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq1" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Estaremos enviando los terrarios en la primera semana de diciembre.</p>
    
</div>

<div class="question" id="question-container2" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq2()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">2. ¿Cómo funciona el envío con plantas?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq2" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Utilizamos envío de UPS para el día siguiente, esto para que las plantas no pasen tanto tiempo en el traslado. Todos pedidos serán envíados de lunes a miércoles, esto para evitar ante cualquier percance, que las plantas pasen el fin de semana en las instalaciones de la mensajería. El envío no tiene costo.</p>
</div>

<div class="question" id="question-container3" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq3()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">3. ¿Cómo lo armo?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq3" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Te recomendamos armar tu terrario tan pronto lo recibas o colocar las plantas en una maceta para utilizarlas más adelante. Recuerda que puedes agregar más plantas ya estando armado el terrario. Sigue las instrucciones incluídas, o visita este <a href="">link.</a></p>
    
</div>

<div class="question" id="question-container4" style="padding: 40px 0 20px 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(17,89,57,.3);" class="question-lillipot preguntas-lillipot" onclick="despliegueFaq4()">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #115939;">4. ¿Qué tipos de pago aceptan?</h3>
    <span style=" display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}</span>
    <p id="esconder_faq4" style="display: none; padding: 20px; text-align: center; color: #115939;">Aceptamos pagos con tarjeta de crédito, débito, PayPal, pagos en efectivo en Oxxo o transferencia interbancaria SPEI.</p>
    
</div>
```

Then all you need to do to refactor this code is the following:

```js
let questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

for (var i=0;i<questions.length;i++) {
    var x = questions[i];
    if (x.style.display === "none"){
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
```

At this point you could also reevaluate whether you actually need all those separate `id` values. If you don't need to identify them separately it might be worthwhile to just get rid of them for simplicity's sake.